# Why don't javascript iterables support map/foreach/etc

Tags: typescript

If you can use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over an iterable, why doesn't the standard support using `.map(...` on the iterable? This could be just a syntatic sugar for a generator comprising `for...of` with the provided function run in the for loop.

For example, it could be sugar for:

```
function* map(iterable, mapFn) {
  for (const item of iterable) {
    yield mapFn(item);
  }
}
```

**What is the fundamental limitation that prevents this behavior?**

Bonus points: Do JS engines (e.g., v8) make a copy of the data for a conversion to an array if the subsequent functions do not mutate it? For example:

```
const res = [...extremelyLargeSet].reduce((acc,cur)=>acc+cur.value,0)
```

I generally like `Set` and `Map` because they are the most appropriate data structure for some applications, but in some situations I am concerned about the potential duplications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no fundamental technical reason other iterables don't have array-like methods, and [good news, there's a stage-3 proposal for iteratable helpers](https://tc39.es/proposal-iterator-helpers/) to get those added in. There are also some [other proposals](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Atc39+iterable+OR+set+OR+map&type=source) at various stages dealing with related issues with iterator/iterable/Set/Map.

As for your second question (please don't post two questions in one, in the future!): spread gives back a shallow copy of the iterable, and as far as I can tell V8 at least never double-checks if it really *needs* to do that. The original iterable should just be GC'd once its not being used. If you're concerned about the memory overhead of holding onto extremely large data (until the JS engine cleans it up, which may or may not have to wait for Mark/Sweep/Compact phases), then it's possible that that data is too large to conveniently be processed in memory anyway (and should be done in a DB or on disk) — but worrying about the size of an array that's destined to be garbage collected, if it's not currently causing any problems, is definitely a premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "iterable" is duck typed in Javascript, similar to Python. This means that there's no single superclass that all iterables inherit from: the term "iterable" is merely defined to be "any object that has a method with the name `Symbol.iterator`". This means that there's no class we could *define* these helper functions on.

This is in contrast to a language like Ruby that *does* define an `Enumerable` module. In Ruby, every enumerable object (the Ruby equivalent of "iterable") actually mixes in the module `Enumerable`, so all of the helpers are defined over there. But there's no module or class to define `map` and company on in Javascript. On the other hand, if Javascript supported [extension methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method), then a function like `map` could be defined top-level and then a `.map` call could be syntactically converted into a top-level function call. But, again, Javascript doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone who comes across this, JS _sort of_ has extension methods by modifying the root object's prototype, but that's brittle, generally frowned on, and not as clean as in OO languages.

And while any object _could_ implement `@@iterator` incorrectly, any builtin type that has a `@@iterator` properly implements the protocol, meaning all builtin iterables _can_ get `map`, `filter`, etc. if those are [defined on the Iterator prototype](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers#proposal) (and we just have to hope any custom Iterators implement that correctly).